# How to find the MGF and PGF of the random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be an integer-valued RV with PGF $P(s)$, and suppose that the MGF
$M(s)$ exists for $s \in (— s_o, s_o)$, $so > 0$. How are $M(s)$ and $P(s)$ related?

My attempt has been:

$M(s) = E(e^{sX})= \sum_{k= -\infty}^{\infty} e^{sx_k}p_k = e^s  \sum_{k= -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{{x_k}^k}{k!}p_k$

$P(s) = E(s^X) =  \sum_{k= -\infty}^{\infty} s^{x_k} p_k$

I am not sure how to proceed after this or the formulas are correct or not.I am self studying statistics and i am finding a bit of difficulty in generating functions. Can someone help me out in this problem..

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the MGF and PGF as being the Laplace and Z transforms of your random variable, respectively.

Both transforms in fact contain the same information. Namely, if you consider the MGF $M_X(s)$ and the PGF $G_X(z)$ (notice that I don't use the same parameter here to avoid confusion), you can introduce the change of variable $\log z=s$ so that $z=e^s$. Then, you will obtain $$G_X(z)=E[z^X]=E[e^{sX}]=M_X(s)=M_X(\log z).$$

Also, due to the above transformation, the probability generating function can only be performed on positive integer valued random variables, so in your question, the correct formula for $P(s)$ is $$P(s)=E[s^X]=\sum_{k\geq 0}s^{x_k}Pr(X=k).$$